# altering the depth/dimensions of a voice with the help of Eq and reverb... how? 

Tags: sound-design

i'd wanna know if i can reduce or increase the depth of a voice with the help of Eq and reverb ...its not the basic depth that i want its the feeling of dimensions?

i am working as an engineer for past 2 years 
i feel this is a gr8 place to clear my doubts

Answer (score 2):

I asked the same question 2 days ago and i got some really great answers!
[Link to my question](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/10395/how-to-give-a-feeling-of-distance-position)

Answer (score 2):

@Warren, Hi, i'm going to guess that by depth you mean distance from front to back? If so then you're probably familiar with how sound behaves as it moves further away; less bass and less highs with more reflected/reverberant energy.

Feelings of "dimension" in other words "feeling of or sense of space" are essentially linked to the ratio of Early Reflections/Direct Sound. An easy way to hear this is to talk with your hand in front of your face, walk towards a wall whilst talking etc.

How to mimic this? Vocal Centre Panned
Reverb doesn't work, it'll make it too distant sounding.

You need to re-create early reflections appropriate to the size/dimensions of space you want to create.
A wall 6 feet (2m) away will be a 12ft (4m) return journey, approx 1ms per foot {0.3ms/m} means that if you add a delayed version of the sound, 12ms, to the right speaker channel at an appropriate level (try less than -10dB with judicious EQ the sound will begin to "widen"

Tip, do not use identical delay times EQ or volume settings for the left channel otherwise the effect sound will centralise behind the main vocal causing it to recede into the distance.

Some reverbs allow you just to use only the Early Reflections, you may have better luck with this.

**Recording Tip** I can highly recommend using MS (Mid-Side) for vocal recording. This allows you to add a "flavour" of the room you recorded in.

**Re-Recording Tip** Send the vocal to a loudspeaker in an appropriate reflective space. Re-record the vocal using MS and a little EQ on the mix.

Regards
James

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has already been said:

How you record the voice is also important: position and placement of the microphone. It's tougher to get it to sound correct with post processing if the mic is too close or too far away. Not impossible, but tough.

If you have control over the recording process, try and get it right at the source. Or record with multiple microphones if you aren't sure.